# Make a relationship between two tables though another

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Condominium(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'condominiums'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    properties = db.relationship('Property', backref='condominiums')

class Property(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'properties'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    condominium_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('condominiums.id'))
    listings = db.relationship('Listing', backref='property')

class Listing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'listings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    property_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('properties.id'))
```

I want to list all `listings` for a given `condominium`, like this:

```
SELECT listings.* FROM condominiums
INNER JOIN properties ON properties.condominium_id = condominiums.id
INNER JOIN listings ON listings.property_id = properties.id
WHERE condominiums.id = 1;
```

I want to be able to get a `listing` collection like this:

```
condominium = Condominium.query.get(1)
listings = condominium.listings
```

How can I achieve that using SQLAlchemy? Is it possible?

Comment: I think this is more of a data design question. Does each Property have one Condominium and each Condominium have many Properties? Or is it the other way around, maybe? If you have multiple Listings per Property and multiple Condominiums per Property, then you have a many-to-many relationship between Listings and Condominiums *through* the Property table. But if that's what you want, Condominium should have an FK to Property, not the other way around.

Comment: It's also possible you want each Listing to have an FK to Condominium if the Property isn't what links them. Tough to know what your design should look like, but SQLAlchemy shouldn't be the limiting factor here.

Comment: @dyrlei Basically what I have is: condominium has many properties and properties has many listings. The design is quite simple. I just want to get all listings for a given condominium. I can get all properties for a given condominium and then all listings for each property I got, but I want to get all listings directly, like: Condominium.query.get(1).listings. It's just a SELECT with 2 JOINS, but I don't know how can I define that relationship using SQLAlchemy and if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Condominium is 1:M to Property which is 1:M to Listing and that all foreign keys are well-defined, you can get all Listings for Condominium with id 123 thus:

```
session.query(Listing).join(Property).join(Condominium).filter(Condominium.id=123)
```

Comment: Ohh, that's it! I just have to begin with the listing and filter by the condominium, I was trying to make it backwards. Thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: @stefanobaldo Awesome, glad to hear that works for you.